Calculating structural stability of a doped plane
The following image indicates an equation published on a reserach paper which was used to calculate structural stability in a metal atom-substituted graphene sheet. Can anyone tell me if we should calculate the energy of term Ec as vc-relaxed or relaxed?

You should always relax your structure fully when calculating stability, which includes lattice parameters; however, for a 2D plane you only want to relax the in-plane lattice parameters. If you relax the out-of-plane parameter then you will almost always find that a 3D structure is lower energy - in your case, you will discover graphite! This is not what you are interested in, so you need to keep the graphene sheets well-separated.

Thank you @Phil Hasnip I have added 20 angstroms vacuum seperation for periodic images.
